# Remember user session for several weeks?

Tags: shiro

If i remember correctly, public services like google usually offer the ability to avoid the login process for 2 weeks.

This way, even with the tab closed, browser or even OS restart, the user can still access the web page as the subject without having to re-login.

The questions are :

1. To implement this in Apache Shiro, it's just about the session timeout isnt it, something like **globalSessionTimeout** ? This way the session is stored and kept alive for 2 weeks before timeout-ing by itself out of inactivities.
2. This is --**not**-- the same as the "*Remember Me*" feature of Shiro where the *authenticated* and *remembered* are differentiated, correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Shiro or web session will retain authentication state, i.e. if a user has actually proven their identity in addition to other state (session attributes, etc).

The "Remember Me" feature in Shiro only sets an identity cookie that tells the server who the end-user *probably* is, but this cookie *does not* retain authentication state.  The reasons for these two different approaches are clearly explained in Shiro's documentation: [Remembered vs. Authenticated](http://shiro.apache.org/authentication.html#Authentication-Rememberedvs.Authenticated).

I'm not sure how Google implements their solution, but I'm fairly certain it is not session based.  Google aims to be server stateless whenever possible - maintaining millions of sessions for GMail (for example) is technical overhead they'd probably rather not deal with.  GMail probably retains authentication state in [browser local storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) (or some custom equivalent) ensuring all state is in the client.

In any event, if I had to take a guess, it probably works like this:

When you authenticate with the server, Google probably takes a bunch of information about you and your computer at that time (time, IP address, browser information, user id, etc) and computes a cryptographic hash (aka 'digest') of that information and sets the hash value as a cookie or in browser local storage.

The next time you visit the server, they probably look at that value, perform the same cryptographic hash of the relevant information in the current request, and if the hash they compute matches the one in the cookie, they can be mostly sure that it is still you on a specific computer, and allow you to use the app without logging in.

This behavior is like Shiro Remember Me ++.  They remember who the user is *without using a session*, but also other information that can give them a higher degree of certainty that the user is really who they expect.

To approximate the same behavior using Shiro, then yes, you would have to extend Session times for 2 weeks.  The difference is that my guess at Google's solution does not require any server state at all, while Sessions do.

Comment: I am super excited about this. But i could not googled out the Shiro Remember Me ++ thing. Is this feature available in Shiro already or i still have to manually collect, hash and do the cookie stuff?

Comment: Hi @AlbertKam this is not available in Shiro today - we'd love any contributions back to the project if you implement it!

Comment: Hi @bertie as per Les Hazlewood its seems to be HMAC authentication. You can do the same by adding HMACRealm in your security manager.